# How to fetch system info from jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, web-scraping, jenkins-api

Jenkins has many api's but do we have anything using which we can fetch systeminfo via python code or web scraping.

The system info will be present on the web page http://your.jenkins.url/systemInfo

Comment: Are you saying that the system info already *is* present at that URL, or that you somehow want to *make* it so that the system info is available at that URL?

Comment: It's already available, basically, it's available for every Jenkins master.

Comment: You say the system info is already available at that URL, so then yes, you can use web scraping to get the information from the webpage. "How can I web scrape this page?" is too broad a question though - you would need to be specific in terms of what information you wanted to extract.

Comment: yes I got that info but it looks like computer name env variable info is only present for windows host and not for all